# Python Open Multiple URL Connections - urllib2

Tags: python, facebook, twitter, connection, urllib2

I'm trying to create a python script that will allow me to load up multiple connections similar to having multiple tabs open on a browser, more explicitly I have a code like this:

https://github.com/eWizardII/SOC357-Twitter-Facebook-Project/blob/master/chuck.py

Using urlv, etc, I load up multiple connections to the API, however I want to make it so that I call all 5 at the same time instead of in succession. I have looked into things like twisted and tidy, but I don't know how to use them to help me.

Thanks,
Solomon

Comment: Related: [Reading a website with asyncore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1367453/279627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create HttpHandlers to handle asynchronous http requests (asynchronous as far as your code is concerned, not when it comes to actual network operations).

Try this:

```
import urllib2

class MyHttpHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_response(self, request, response):
        for l in response:
            print l
        return response

u = urllib2.build_opener(MyHttpHandler())
for i in range(1, 5):
    u.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped in terms of speeding things up as seen here: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/falcon.py I also attempted to use kaloyan's threading idea. I guess the only other speed improvement I can do is look into how to make the connections actually in parallel, like opening up 20 links at the same time on a browser but in different tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the help I used your comments and kaloyan to get it to work. For ref: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py

Answer (score 4):

Use the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
python chuck.py "request 1" &
python chuck.py "request 2" &
python chuck.py "request 3" &
python chuck.py "request 4" &
python chuck.py "request 5" &
```

This will run 5 copies of your program.  It will tie up as many cores and CPUs as it can.  And -- bonus -- no programming using subprocess or threading or anything.

If all 5 are supposed to do somehow different things, then you'll have to provide some kind of arguments or options.  Look into `argparse` for a way to gather command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks, yea this will help with the final program, as the goal is to make each program as fast as it can be then just use a similar shell implementation to the one you have shown here.

Comment: @eWizardII: If each program simply does `urllib2` retrieve or open/read and file write, they're already as fast as they can be.  You don't need any more code than the simplest possible Python plus multiple processes to achieve the maximum speed the machine is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) library. That is one of the things it is best suited.

Comment: Potentially like this then? https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/falcon.py Though when I time it verse without threading it seems the sum of the times add up to the same as without threading. I know there is a alot of information out there about how GIL and Python threading work, etc, but I assume the threading you are suggesting is something like this http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html since basically the issue is if one json file is being downloaded how do I start a parallel connection say for 4 more.

Comment: Okay so I was able to set it up with the link I posted above and using what @01001111 said so if anyone finds this question here is what I ended up with https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py Thanks!